# Next Js project getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, fetch-api

I'm learning Next.js and run into a problem. I was following a tutorial on youtube to make a google clone with the next.js + tailwind. So the problem is when I add `export async function getServerSideProps()` I get an error **invalid JSON response body.** **Reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**
Seems I am doing everything exactly as the instructor but he doesn't get any error.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const useDummyData = false;

  const data = await fetch(
    `https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1?
    key=${API_KEY}&cx=${CONTEXT_KEY}&q=${context.query.term}`
  ).then((response) => response.json());

  return {
    props: {
      results: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Is the URL in the request you're making correct? If you make the exact same request from Postman, what do you get in the response?

Comment: Thanks! I figured out it was a bad url. Should have used https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1 instead of https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1